# UTC time to time based by timezone offset

Tags: php, datetime

I am saving all the times in MySQL in UTC(0), so I could change them later while I'm showing the times for the users with different time zones, for saving into db, I use:

```
function get_utc(){
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    }
$now = get_utc();
```

And now I want to convert those times into different timezones based by timezones offset, I am using this function:

```
function utc_and_timezone($utc_time, $offset) {
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($offset, strtotime($utc_time)));
    }
```

So for example,  if the UTC time is: 2013-01-30 21:06:29
Applying the +5 timezone on that time is easy to find:

```
$new_time =  utc_and_timezone("2013-01-30 21:06:29", "+5 hours"); // Works Fine
```

It works JUST fine with offsets like 5,6 or other integers, BUT with some other like +3.5, +2.5 this is not working:

```
$new_time =  utc_and_timezone("2013-01-30 21:06:29", "+5.5 hours"); // NOT WORKING
```

Anyone knows why?!
Any better solutions for making UTC times in different timezones...?

Thanks

---

**SHORT QUESTION:**
I want to show a UTC time like `2013-01-30 21:06:29` in `+3.5` timezone, how is that possible?

Comment: Do you have the user's time zone stored in MySQL? If so, it'd be easier to convert in your query.

Comment: I want to show a UTC time like `2013-01-30 21:06:29` in `+3.5` timezone, how is that possible?

Comment: Can you answer my question first?

Comment: Yes, I have it in DB and it's also available as a session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the PHP side, you can try:

```
$utc_time = '2013-01-30 21:06:29';
$offset = '3.5';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($utc_time) + (3600 * $offset) );
//Returns 2013-01-31 00:36:29

$utc_time = '2013-01-30 21:06:29';
$offset = '-5.5';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($utc_time) + (3600 * $offset) );
//Returns 2013-01-30 15:36:29
```

On the MySQL side, you can just use [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-01-30 21:06:29','+00:00','+03:30');
//Returns January, 31 2013 00:56:29+0000

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2013-01-30 21:06:29','+00:00','-05:50');
//Returns January, 30 2013 15:16:29+0000
```